# Translate a Python regular expression to Perl

Tags: python, regex, perl

I am not the greatest at regular expressions so translating them from one lang to another can be a daunting task.

```
tre = re.compile("///--STRING TEXT ONE. Ends with the word EDIT.(?:.*)--///(?:(?:.*\n))*///--END is the first word in STRING TEXT TWO--///")
result = tre.sub(motionBlur_text, configContents)
```

If you guys could help me move this to perl(which i hear is better for reg expressions) that would be really cool.

Comment: Regular expression library probably isn't a good reason. Python regular expressions are great. I don't know about Perl but I would be surprised if it's much better.

Comment: What are you doing that you need Perl regex?

Comment: @Joe: Perl regex has support for Unicode character matching (I am mostly referring to `\p`), which Python `re` lacks support. Apart from that, I think Python `re` is quite OK for most purpose. Python `re2` package does have support for those, though, and quite powerful (I think it supports quite a lot of bells and whistles in Perl).

Comment: Good to know! I didn't realise that `re` wasn't Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex in Perl is the same :

```
my $re = qr#///--STRING TEXT ONE. Ends with the word EDIT.(?:.*)--///(?:(?:.*\n))*///--END is the first word in STRING TEXT TWO--///#;
```

Answer (score 0):

Compilation is done via the `qr//` operator. You can use (mostly any) character instead of '/'. I'll use braces since that's what Perl Best Practices recommends:

```
my $tre = qr{///--STRING TEXT ONE. Ends with the word EDIT.(?:.*)--///(?:(?:.*\n))*///--END is the first word in STRING TEXT TWO--///};
```

To perform the substitution in-place (see [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)):

```
$motionBlur_text =~ s/$tre/$configContents/g;
```

To perform the substitution on a copy of the string, and return it (Perl 5.14+)

```
my $result = $motionBlur_text =~ s/$tre/$configContents/gr;
```